# Append from a blender file with different unit scale

Tags: transforms, units

I have one architecture project, two blender files.
Imperial unit system (feet), separate units (inch) in each of the two files.

The idea was modeling different components in different files and then safely append integrate object by object or collection by collection to one complete project file.

While modeling hundreds of objects I did not see that, (for unknown reasons) one of the blender files had a scene unit scale of 0.025400 while the other blender file has a unit scale of 1.

Of course when I change the unit scale from .025400 to 1, every included scene object dimensions gets huge and unwanted values.

Is there a way to change scene unit scale value while not affecting individual dimensions and localization objects values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with just selecting all scene objects and simply scaling them to correct dimensions in the newly set scene unit scale. That's basically what is needed to be done in this case. You probably want to set your Transform Pivot Point to 3d Cursor

[image]

and snap the cursor to the center of the scene and you may want to apply scale to all your objects after the operation. It's as simple as selecting all with <kbd>a</kbd> in object mode, hitting <kbd>s</kbd> and typing the numerical value. You can enter advanced input mode by hitting <kbd>*</kbd> while in scale operation and then if you are converting from 1 to 0.0254 then just type 1/0.0254 and it will calculate the value while scaling. If it's other way around and you are converting from 0.0254 to 1 then it's just 0.0254/1 so 0.0254. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> -> <kbd>s</kbd> to apply scale.

Comment: Your input looks quite pertinent to this situation, Martynas. Still have a few tests to do but chances are that your answer will allow me to harmonize scale for all scenes. Should be back soon to close this question.